# How to incorporate the use of SSRS Dataset parameters with Timestamp escape clause?

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008

I've the following WHERE CLAUSE of a SQL Query String in the SSRS Dataset:

```
WHERE "Input_date" >={ts '2009-01-01'}
AND   "Input_date" < {ts '2009-12-31'}
```

And now, I'd like to use report parameter to wrap up the dates in the SQL statement, i.e.
@indate1, and @indate2.

I've tried this, but error occurs:

```
WHERE "Input_date" >={ts @indate1}
AND   "Input_date" < {ts @indate2}
```

Please kindly advise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

What have you done to add these parameters? I assume that you have altered the dataset query with the changes you have posted in your question. There are two more steps you need to perform to make this work:

1. **Define a new parameter** to the parameters folder. Right click the parameters folder and choose Add parameter. Specify which values you want the user to be able to select. Repeat for the second parameter.
2. **Add the parameters to the dataset** you are using for the report. This can be done in the parameters section when you edit the dataset. Add two parameters with the names `@indate1` and `@indate2`, and set each parameters value to the parameters you defined in step one.
3. **Alter the SQL statement** as you described in your post. I would think that your SQL should look something like this (assuming `Input_date` is a column in your table):

`WHERE Input_date >= @indate1 AND Input_date < @indate2`

This is specific to the BIDS 2008 version of Visual Studio. If you are using report builder or something else, please let me know, and I can change the instructions a bit.